# MySQL: Get result from MySQL procedure call

Tags: mysql, procedure

Situation: Having a SQL procedure which "returns" result via "SELECT x" statements. For some reasons it is not allowed to change it to a function or changing that procedure in any way. How can I obtain the result like:

```
set @result = 0;
@result = call SomeProcedure(@p1, @p2);
```

But since it is a procedure not a function above code won't compile/work. How can I achieve that in MySQL. In C++ it works but in MySQL I found no way ...

Comment: in mysql you can: 1) use a function. 2) use a procedure, and inside it set a global variable that you can select later from outside. 3) from a procedure, you can check if some of the params are of type out, probably the result is already in some of your p1 or p2 when the procedure ends. option 1 is not available, but probably you can read the syntax of the procedure and see if it is posible to use the 2nd or 3rd option

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

Result sets returned from `select ...` will always be returned to the caller of the first procedure, even if you make several levels of sub calls.

Functions return a value (but not a result set) that you can use inside other procedures or functions.

Your only option is to either set session variables or to store the result in a temporary table that the calling procedure knows about.

Comment: Thank you for response. I'll change the procedure to a function (since it is the right choice for that task) some day (just need an int result)